# Как проверить прокси на работоспасобность с помощю Python

Tags: python, сеть, proxy

У меня проблема с моей страной. У моей страны жесткий контроль Интернета. Практический все VPN не работают. Но обхожу блокировку с помощью Proxifier, но и для него надо: собирать список прокси и каждую отдельно проверять. Это занимает ужасно много времени. Я решил все это ускорить с помощью python. У меня пока знания языка и представление о сетях начальный уровень. По этому если знаете как это можно реализовать помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.10.10:3333',
  'https': 'http://10.10.10.10:8888',
}

response=requests.get('http://example.org любой сайт для проверки' , proxies=proxies)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Success!')
```

Можно из файла подставлять список адресов и портов